# How can I make a white box in PyQt?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I have a PyQt application that has a widget called Deck

```
class Deck(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, filename, parent):
        super(Deck, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setMinimumSize(100, 150)
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: white;')

        label = QtGui.QLabel("deck", self)
        label.show()
```

I expected the Deck widget to be all white, but it is only under the label, although it accepts clicks on its 100x150 area and adjusts its hbox:s size.

[image]

Edit:
The surrounding layout.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
#import qt4reactor
#qt4reactor.install()

from deck import Deck

class Duel(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Duel, self).__init__()

        topArea = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        topArea.addStretch(1)
        d = Deck(sys.argv[1], self)
        d.show()
        topArea.addWidget(d)

        bottomArea = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        d = Deck(sys.argv[2], self)
        d.show()
        bottomArea.addWidget(d)
        bottomArea.addStretch(1)

        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addLayout(topArea)
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        vbox.addLayout(bottomArea)
        self.setLayout(vbox)


def main():
    root = Duel()
    root.show()

    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I tried your example and it shows the color correctly http://pastebin.com/ShhZV2Vw I imagine it's something related on the method you use to pack it.

Comment: @pygabriel I probably forgot to call show on the deck. Will check when I'm home. Why does the label show although its parent is hidden?

Comment: @pygabriel your code works. Mine works too if I put the Deck as root. I'll post some more code.